# Convert Mongodb BSON id to integer String

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

MongoDB uses primary key as 12 byte BSON id. I would like to convert it to Strings with each character as an integer so that it is more human readable. Now, I cant convert it directly to integer or long since that will 4 or 8 bytes respectively. Hence need to convert to String but with integer characters.

Following link converts byte array in bson to long but at the cost of loss in precision, hence resulting in collisions:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/PfA-PTORx8g

Any pointers?

Comment: Why don't you use String or Integer as Id for your collection? UUID might be good approach

Comment: Trying to stick to mongodb recommendation of using bson ObjectIds. Will think of this as a last resort.

Comment: Never mind , used BigInteger(Java 7)

Comment: @JeetKumar Have you solved it?

Comment: @chemitaxis I converted the Bson byte array to BigInteger. More detail about BigInteger :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html